# (ViewFlipper) Disable a next button in the last view?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm trying to do a quiz app which has a ViewFlipper and a next button and I want to disable the next button or make it do other commands like starting a new activity when it comes to the last view, is that possible?

Java file

```
    Button Result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    Button Next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
    ViewFlipper flipp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipp);

    if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == flipp.getChildCount()){
       Next.setText("Result");
    }
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ViewFlipper flipp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipp);
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(Next.getText().equals("Result")){
                finalResult();
                ResultC = 0;
                ResultW = 0;
            }else{flipp.showNext();};
        }
    });
```

xml file

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Q1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Q2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Q4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: Hi, could you post a bit more code, like how you create all your view and etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if .getDisplayedChild() == .getChildCount() when you press the Next button. If its true you have reached the last slide and you can run you other command.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, I've posted my code I must have written something wrong could you check out please.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the text of the button using `button.setText("New label")` and in OnclickListener follow this style

```
if(!last)
{
   //your  usual code for onclick listener
}
else 
{
    // your code for the last view 
}
```

**-----EDITED-----**

This is how I advised

```
boolean last=false;
Button Result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
Button Next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
ViewFlipper flipp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipp);

if(flipp.getDisplayedChild() == flipp.getChildCount()){
   Next.setText("Result");
   last=true;
}
Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ViewFlipper flipp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipp);
    @Override

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(last)){
            finalResult();
            ResultC = 0;
            ResultW = 0;
        }else{flipp.showNext();};
    }
});
```

Comment: What does "!last" stand for?

Comment: set a `boolen` call it `last`, Intialize it to `false` when its last view set it to true . `last=true`

Comment: The problem is "getDisplayedChild()" is always equals 0 though the "getChildCount()" works pretty fine, is there any other way I can get the DisplayedChild?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one


if (flipper.indexOfChild(flipper.getCurrentView()) == flipper.getChildCount()){

  button.settext("Start New Quiz");

}

  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                              if(button.gettext.equals("Start New Quiz")){
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        DashBoardClass.class);

                startActivity(in);

                 }else{

                   //do what you want here 
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, I've posted my code I must have written something wrong could you check out please.

Comment: you have written this twice y ???

   ViewFlipper flipp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipp);

one above listener and one inside listener ?

Comment: I had to write it again inside listener cos i had this error (Variable "flipp" is accessed from within inner class. Needs to be declared final.)

Comment: declare it as final then not a problem. . by doing this you creating another instance for it which is a wrong approach. . declare it as final

Comment: Thank you, still the getChild thing doesn't work, Do i have to do something with layouts? Or import something?

Comment: flipper.indexOfChild(flipper.getCurrentView())
i used this to get the index now. . . .it must do it now